# Assign value of a field into a hidden field

Tags: symfony

How can I assign value of `email` field into a hidden field called `hiddenEmail` in form below? When I do `form_widget(form.hiddenEamil)` in twig, the value should match the value of the actual Email field.

```
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'Email'))
        ->add('hiddenEmail', 'hidden', array('data' => ......... ))
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the data of the model with this:

`$builder->getData()->getEmail()`

Only if you set the correct `data_class` in the `setDefaultOptions` method.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for that. +1 and accept it shortly.